# Как сделать анимацию более плавную?

Tags: javascript, codemirror

Как сделать что бы в iframe, в html виде все появлялось более плавно и без скачков?
Вот пример https://jsfiddle.net/x69waxjv/1/

```
    <textarea id="coder" style="display:none;">
  <table border="1">
   <caption>Таблица размеров обуви</caption>
   <tr>
    <th>Россия</th>
    <th>Великобритания</th>
    <th>Европа</th>
    <th>Длина ступни, см</th>
   </tr>
   <tr><td>34,5</td><td>3,5</td><td>36</td><td>23</td></tr>
   <tr><td>35,5</td><td>4</td><td>36⅔</td><td>23–23,5</td></tr>
   <tr><td>36</td><td>4,5</td><td>37⅓</td><td>23,5</td></tr>
   <tr><td>36,5</td><td>5</td><td>38</td><td>24</td></tr>
   <tr><td>37</td><td>5,5</td><td>38⅔</td><td>24,5</td></tr>
   <tr><td>38</td><td>6</td><td>39⅓</td><td>25</td></tr>
   <tr><td>38,5</td><td>6,5</td><td>40</td><td>25,5</td></tr>
   <tr><td>39</td><td>7</td><td>40⅔</td><td>25,5–26</td></tr>
   <tr><td>40</td><td>7,5</td><td>41⅓</td><td>26</td></tr>
   <tr><td>40,5</td><td>8</td><td>42</td><td>26,5</td></tr>
   <tr><td>41</td><td>8,5</td><td>42⅔</td><td>27</td></tr>
   <tr><td>42</td><td>9</td><td>43⅓</td><td>27,5</td></tr>
   <tr><td>43</td><td>9,5</td><td>44</td><td>28</td></tr>
   <tr><td>43,5</td><td>10</td><td>44⅔</td><td>28–28,5</td></tr>
   <tr><td>44</td><td>10,5</td><td>45⅓</td><td>28,5–29</td></tr>
   <tr><td>44,5</td><td>11</td><td>46</td><td>29</td></tr>
   <tr><td>45</td><td>11,5</td><td>46⅔</td><td>29,5</td></tr>
   <tr><td>46</td><td>12</td><td>47⅓</td><td>30</td></tr>
   <tr><td>46,5</td><td>12,5</td><td>48</td><td>30,5</td></tr>
   <tr><td>47</td><td>13</td><td>48⅔</td><td>31</td></tr>
   <tr><td>48</td><td>13,5</td><td>49⅓</td><td>31,5</td></tr>
  </table>
        </textarea>
<textarea id="code"></textarea>
<iframe id="preview"></iframe>
```

var delay = 15;

```
// Initialize CodeMirror editor with a nice html5 canvas demo.
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('code'), {
  mode: 'text/html',
  theme: "material",
  lineNumbers: true,
  viewportMargin: Infinity,
  styleActiveLine: true,
  tabMode: 'indent',
  matchBrackets: true,
  lineWrapping: true
});

 editor.on("change", function() {
        clearTimeout(delay);
        delay = setTimeout(updatePreview, 14);
      });
      function updatePreview() {
        var previewFrame = document.getElementById('preview');
        var preview =  previewFrame.contentDocument ||  previewFrame.contentWindow.document;
        preview.open();
        preview.write(editor.getValue());
        preview.close();
      }

// Сколько символов уже обработано
var count = 0;
// Пример текста для анимации
var text = $("#coder").val();

// Устанавливаем таймер на повторение с указанной задержкой
var w = setInterval(function() {
  // Если обработан весь текст, удаляем таймер
  if (count == text.length) {
    clearInterval(w);
    return;
  }
  // Добавляем в редактор по 1 символу за раз 
  editor.setValue(editor.getValue() + text.charAt(count));

  // Увеличиваем счетчик обработанных символов из текста
  count++;
}, delay);
```

Answer (score 1):

изменить значение var delay на то которое вас удовлетворит. например var delay = 65;

можно еще так плавно показать таблицу

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#coder').fadeIn(5000);
});
```

```css
#coder{
height:100vh;
width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <table border="1"  id="coder" style="display:none;">
   <caption>Таблица размеров обуви</caption>
   <tr>
    <th>Россия</th>
    <th>Великобритания</th>
    <th>Европа</th>
    <th>Длина ступни, см</th>
   </tr>
   <tr><td>34,5</td><td>3,5</td><td>36</td><td>23</td></tr>
   <tr><td>35,5</td><td>4</td><td>36⅔</td><td>23–23,5</td></tr>
   <tr><td>36</td><td>4,5</td><td>37⅓</td><td>23,5</td></tr>
   <tr><td>36,5</td><td>5</td><td>38</td><td>24</td></tr>
   <tr><td>37</td><td>5,5</td><td>38⅔</td><td>24,5</td></tr>
   <tr><td>38</td><td>6</td><td>39⅓</td><td>25</td></tr>
   <tr><td>38,5</td><td>6,5</td><td>40</td><td>25,5</td></tr>
   <tr><td>39</td><td>7</td><td>40⅔</td><td>25,5–26</td></tr>
   <tr><td>40</td><td>7,5</td><td>41⅓</td><td>26</td></tr>
   <tr><td>40,5</td><td>8</td><td>42</td><td>26,5</td></tr>
   <tr><td>41</td><td>8,5</td><td>42⅔</td><td>27</td></tr>
   <tr><td>42</td><td>9</td><td>43⅓</td><td>27,5</td></tr>
   <tr><td>43</td><td>9,5</td><td>44</td><td>28</td></tr>
   <tr><td>43,5</td><td>10</td><td>44⅔</td><td>28–28,5</td></tr>
   <tr><td>44</td><td>10,5</td><td>45⅓</td><td>28,5–29</td></tr>
   <tr><td>44,5</td><td>11</td><td>46</td><td>29</td></tr>
   <tr><td>45</td><td>11,5</td><td>46⅔</td><td>29,5</td></tr>
   <tr><td>46</td><td>12</td><td>47⅓</td><td>30</td></tr>
   <tr><td>46,5</td><td>12,5</td><td>48</td><td>30,5</td></tr>
   <tr><td>47</td><td>13</td><td>48⅔</td><td>31</td></tr>
   <tr><td>48</td><td>13,5</td><td>49⅓</td><td>31,5</td></tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Не подходит нужен построковой вывод в iframe